# Why are membership renewal reminders going out for memberships with expiration date 1 year in future?

Tags: drupal, civimember, activities, scheduled-reminders

We are running CivCRM 4.6.14 on Drupal 7.43. (Not updating right now because we are in the middle of a major fundraising campaign and I can't afford any glitches.)

I have a member who is paid up through April 9, 2017. I have membership renewal reminders set up to go out 3 weeks before expiration date, and every 2 weeks until expiration (so they get 2 reminders, basically). This person received reminders March 19 and April 2, 2016, which would be perfect if their membership expired this year. They dutifully sent in a membership renewal payment, and were probably very confused when I called to tell them it's too early to renew (we applied the payment to the aforementioned fundraiser).

Is there some reason that CiviCRM isn't picking up on the year part of the Membership Expiration Date?

[image: screenshot of membership renewal reminder setup]